# Relationship between an Investor's utility function and Stochastic Discount Factor (SDF)

Tags: stochastic-discount, risk-neutral

In real world, it is difficult to arrive at a single price for a risky asset since pricing of a risky asset would depend on the level of risk aversion of the investor. The following equation gives the reason to use risk neutral measure instead of real world measure.

[image: formula]

My question is: Why does the pricing of an asset depend on the investor? Specifically, why does the SDF [image: formula] depend on the investor? An example would be great.

Comment: Think of a world with a representative investor. In the simplest model, the SDF (or pricing kernel) represents his marginal utility (and thus risk aversion). When that agent fears risk a lot, then risky assets need to offer high returns (have low prices).

Comment: I am getting an intuition. Lets assume there are two investors, A & B. A is risk seeking while B is risk averse. According to CAPM model with risk-free asset, there is a linear relationship b/w expected return and risk. Since A is risk seeking, he expects his investments to have higher expected returns, lets say 30% while B expected his investments to have a return of 5%. Does that mean for investor A, 1\$ today is worth 1.3\$ at the end of the year and for investor B it is just 1.05$. Is that why we need to use different discount factors for the two?